# How do I make kafka producer generate events in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-kafka

So, this is the code that I have, do I need to add something to properties?

At first I thought this had to do with partitioning, but it turns out that there's a way to make kafka producer use more threads.

Can someone explain how I can do this?

```
val props = new Properties()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, url)
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, "IdPartitioner")
var kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
```

Comment: Need more context on both your code and the question, but to produce events in parallel, you need multiple threads to produce messages. If the code you include runs in a single thread, your producer can issue only a single message at once. You can still run multiple instances of a single-thread producer through your shell (e.g. `xargs` or GNU parallel). Whether this is viable depends on the logic used to produce your payloads.

Comment: You can run multiple producers which push data to the same topic partition at the same time (although the order of the messages will be determined by the leader of that particular partition).

Comment: Scala threads really have nothing to do with Kafka or Big data, so I would suggest restarting your research with that fact in mind

Comment: I wish I had more details, guys. I have no idea what this means either, the task just tells me that I have to implement a Kafka daemon, that produces events in parallel.

Comment: @ovo https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/ in this link I found `num.replica.fetchers`, isn't this what I want?

Comment: @user10558843 No. `num.replica.fetchers` determines thread count for replication across brokers. This is a server-side setting with no effect on the producer.

Answer (score 0):

> turns out that there's a way to make kafka producer use more threads

Not natively, no. You would have to make a `new Thread` yourself, or use a higher level producing library that might accomplish that for you. Spring Kafka or Akka's Kafka support might be options to look at for that. Or Spark/Flink/Beam (since you had [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop))

Multiple messages will already be sent in a batch, however, and each produced record includes a topic name, and key, so therefore even a single thread is producing "in parallel" to multiple possible brokers

Comment: what about `num.replica.fetchers`? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: That's a broker config, not a producer config

Answer (score 0):

`KafkaProducer` is thread safe by using an internal thread to send messages to brokers.
It does keep an internal cache of messages to be sent out (controlled by `linger.ms`), and it is possible for a scenario like this:

- thread 1 submits message M1 (target = topic1/partition1) to producer
- thread 2 submits message M2 (target = topic2/partition1) to producer
- assumption: t1/p1 & t2/p1 are both hosted on the same broker
- producer's internal thread wakes up and sends both of them in the same request

In general it should suffice for your requirements - you can submit your produce requests in parallel, and they will be organized by KafkaProducer itself.